# Make wget retry original URL after 3XX Redirect

Tags: http, amazon-s3, wget

I have a service that redirects users to temporary pre-signed AWS downloads. These are large files, often 5-10gb. To prevent download sharing, we have a relatively short (30 seconds) valid lifespan.

Everything is working except that on slow internet connections, they tend to fail or get interrupted.  wget has a feature that automatically retries the download. However, instead of retrying the original URL (eg: http://service.com/download/file.zip), wget retries the redirected pre-signed URL (eg: http://service.s3.amazonaws.com/file.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXX&Signature=XXXX&Expires=1468000000)

Since these are large files, and the pre-signed lifespan is so short, that temporary url is no longer valid and the user gets a 403 Forbidden result.

Originally, when we noticed the problem, we were using **302 Found** temporary redirects. A little research seemed to indicate we SHOULD have been using **307 Temporary Redirect**. However, that didn't resolve the problem with wget. For grins and giggles, we tried **303 See Other**, but that didn't work either.

Does anyone have any idea how get wget to retry the original URL instead of the redirected URL?

below is a wget example log:

> --2016-07-06 10:29:51--  https://service.com/download/file.zip
>
> Connecting to service.com (service.com)|10.0.0.1|:443... connected.
>
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
>
> Location:
>   https://service.s3.amazonaws.com/file.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXX&Signature=XXXX&Expires=1468000000
>   [following]
>
> --2016-07-06 10:29:52-- https://service.s3.amazonaws.com/file.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXX&Signature=XXXX&Expires=1468000000
>
> Resolving service.s3.amazonaws.com (service.s3.amazonaws.com)...
>   54.231.12.129
>
> Connecting to service.s3.amazonaws.com
>   (service.s3.amazonaws.com)|54.231.12.129|:443... connected.
>
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
>
> Length: 2070666907 (1.9G) [application/zip]
>
> Saving to:  ‘file.zip’
>
> file.zip 53%[=========> ] 1.03G --.-KB/s in 18m 7s
>
> 2016-07-06 10:47:59 (995 KB/s) - Read error at byte
>   1107205784/2070666907 (The  specified session has been invalidated for
>   some reason.). Retrying.
>
> --2016-07-06 10:48:00-- (try: 2) https://service.s3.amazonaws.com/file.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXX&Signature=XXXX&Expires=1468000000
>
> Connecting to service.s3.amazonaws.com
>   (service.s3.amazonaws.com)|54.231.12.129|:443... connected.
>
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
>
> 2016-07-06 10:48:01 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and a similar answer as @panzerito, but broke it up into a script i called loopdone

```
#!/bin/bash
until `$1`; do sleep 1; echo restarting; done
```

then I can just do `loopdone "wget -c http://my.url/"` (incl quotes) to force it to run again and again (and resume, unless server does not support it) until exit code is 0. (meaning no error)

Answer (score -1):

Bash-code:
initial_error_EXIT_STATUS; until [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; do wget https://example.com/download/file.zip -c; done